# Querying multiple (n=7) classes with pointers

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I need to produce a 'feed' of activities using a PFQueryTableViewController.
I have 7 classes that all contain various activities (ie. `Paymenmt`, `Meal`, `Note`....).  They all contain pointers to the `Child` class.

What I'd like to do is query all these classes to pull the latest activities for the corresponding child and return the objects for each class.

I have tried,

```
   override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

    let queryNote = PFQuery(className: "Note")
    queryNote.whereKey("child", equalTo: passedChildID!)

    let queryPayment = PFQuery(className: "Payment")
    queryItem.whereKey("child", equalTo: passedChildID!)

    return queryNote
}
```

However I am running into trouble as I can't return an array of queries.

I also tried `query.orQueryWithSubQueries` but that only works with queries of the same class.

Parse documentation gives examples, but only for 2 classes (for example).

```
query.whereKey("post", equalTo: PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Post", objectId: "1zEcyElZ80"))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this. You can only query 1 class at a time.

A possible workaround could be to create an `Activity` class that contains the gist of each activity and then add a pointer to the correct activity (i.e. a `Meal`).

In this way, you could query for all the latest activities, and also get the `Meal`/`Payment`/`Note` objects using the `include` statement.

However, each `Activity` object would need to have a column for each type of activity, so if you had 10 different activity classes like `Meal`, the `Activity` class would then need 10 such pointer columns. It is not a beautiful workaround, but it would work.

Not knowing your datamodel I would still advise that you rethink it and see if it could be possible to do it differently. When you develop a mobile application you should plan your data model based on the queries you need to make rather than the old-fashioned RDBM way of thinking strictly in autonomous objects.

Comment: Data model is set up to also support an ember front end for web application, so can't really change that.  When it was only mobile, I did have it set up with a single `Activity` class that held all the various activities.  
I'm wondering if I should just conduct 10 separate queries (there goes my free parse plan), store each in an array and then present the uitableview with separate sections for each.